# Anonymous type in method for Deserializing json from a string to DataContract

Tags: c#, generics, datacontractjsonserializer

I am trying to write an anonymous method for the purpose of deserializing Json to a DataContract. This would allow me to have something re-usable without having to write the same code for each DataContract class I wrote for each json query.

The code I have so far, is as follows :

```
public T Json2Object<T>(string json, Encoding encoding) {
    T result;
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof( T ) );
    using ( Stream s = new MemoryStream( ( encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8 ).GetBytes( json ?? "" ) ) ) {
        result = ser.ReadObject( s ) as T;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It is giving me errors in the IDE as follows :

[image: error]

How can this be adjusted without hard-coding the type so that it works as I intend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as` keyword implies that the type is a reference type, and not a value type. You cannot store `null` in a value type. Thus, you either need to restrict the type `T` to a reference type:

```
public T Json2Object<T>(string json, Encoding encoding) where T : class {
    // ...
}
```

Or *cast* rather than use `as`:

```
public T Json2Object<T>(string json, Encoding encoding) {
    T result;
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof( T ) );
    using ( Stream s = new MemoryStream( ( encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8 ).GetBytes( json ?? "" ) ) ) {
        result = (T)ser.ReadObject( s );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you.   Where you have  `where T : class` do I need to replace `class` with the specific class. For example, if my datacontract class is named `Foo` would this be written as `where T : Foo` or would that `where T : class` still work as you have it written ?

Comment: @KraangPrime Nope, `where T : class` is exactly what you need to write. It restricts `T` to a *reference type*. Note that you will be forbidden from writing `Json2Object<int>(someJson, someEncoding)` since `int` is a value type. If you want to be able to pass in `int`, you'll need to use the casting approach instead.

Comment: That is awesome.  Exactly what I needed.  Thank you  :)